# Default Contact Form Error - Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later Magento CE 1.9.1

Tags: error, default, ce-1.9.1.0

I hope that someone can help me who has possibly been in this situation. I am trying to use the default contact form with Magento 1.9.1 and it is just not working.

I just get the error message

> Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later

I have my Configuration - `System - Disable Email Communications - Set to NO`.

This is my error log

```
   2015-02-22T20:39:46+00:00 ERR (3): 
   exception 'Exception' with message 'This letter cannot be sent.' in         /home/hcflower/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php:374
   Stack trace:
    #0/home/hcflower/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(508): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send('markhulse@live....', NULL, Array)
    #1 /home/hcflower/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php(10        4): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('contacts_email_...', 'custom1', 'markhulse@live....', NULL, Array)
    #2 /home/hcflower/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Contacts_IndexController->postAction()
    #3 /home/hcflower/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('post')
    #4 /home/hcflower/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #5 /home/hcflower/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #6 /home/hcflower/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #7 /home/hcflower/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #8 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess this is a problem with the sendmail configuration, I had similar problems once I configured catchmail wrong (which is a sendmail plugin replacement).

Please check the php error log to see more problems, also here: [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

The exception is thrown here:

```
\Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::send
public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
{
    if (!$this->isValidForSend()) {
        Mage::logException(new Exception('This letter cannot be sent.')); // translation is intentionally omitted
        return false;
    }
```

So this is false:

```
public function isValidForSend()
{
    return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
        && $this->getSenderName()
        && $this->getSenderEmail()
        && $this->getTemplateSubject();
}
```

I recommend to use xdebug or any other debugger of your choice to check what of these four things is wrong.